# I will make a good student of you yet

Tags: meaning

This sentence make me confused about what it is expressing. Is it saying I want to make you become better at studying but the use of word yet is weird, so am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is going to eventually make you a good student but it will take some time.

In Google's dictionary, there is this definition:

> from now into the future for a specified length of time. "I hope to continue for some time yet"

The "yet" in your sentence means it will take a bit of time, showing the effort that the speaker needs to put into it.